# HTML Forms and jQuery : buttons

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button

I have a form where the data is collected then sent to a PHP page via AJAX. This form has a simple button after the `</form>` tag, it is a "normal" button on which I listen to a click, then perform my AJAX call.

```
<button id="normalbutton">Imabutton</button>
```

Why did I put the button outside ?
Because if the button is inside the `<form>...</form>` tags, even if my form has no action specified, even if the button is not a submit button, the simple fact of clicking on it refreshes the whole page.

How can I deal with buttons inside my form?

So far, the only solution I found is to remove the `<form>...</form>` tags, because I handle the submission with jQuery, and I don't need to have a form anymore. Is this correct according to HTML syntax ? i.e. can we have input tags, for instance, without a parent form ? It works, but is it grammatically correct ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all with HTML5 it's possible to have form elements outside the actual form. You can link both [using the `form`-attribute on the button](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-form):

> The form element that the button is associated with (its form owner). The value of the attribute must be the id attribute of a  element in the same document. If this attribute is not specified, the  element must be a descendant of a form element. This attribute enables you to place  elements anywhere within a document, not just as descendants of their  elements.

Besides that, if you don't specify the `type`-attribute for a `button`-element its type is `submit` by default. So clicking this button will always submit the form. You have two options:

**Option 1:** [set `type="button"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)
**Option 2:** prevent submitting of the form:

```
$('#normalbutton').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Note: it is also possible to use `return false;` instead of `event.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<button type="button" id="normalbutton">Imabutton</button>` inside a `<form>` and it should work like a normal button and not refresh.

Answer (score 1):

From the question, it seems as if you want to perform AJAX via the form you are using.

So, first off, there is no need of using `form` tag while using AJAX. The `form` tag along with its attributes `method` and `action` sends a non asynchronous request to the script specified by the `action` attribute using method specified by the `method` attribute.

But, since HTML is a markup language and to make your markup more semantic, you may use the `form` tag with an `id` attribute.

Next thing, regarding buttons; you may use either the `input` tag with attribute `type` set to `button` or `button` tag with attribute `type` set to `button` as by default buttons in `form` tag are considered to be of type `submit`

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 0):

When you do not specify `type` of the button element it's a submit type by default. Use `<button type="button" id="normalbutton">Imabutton</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can even use button type `submit`.
All you have to do when a user clicks on the button is use `preventDefault();`.

```
$(function(){
  $('#buttonId').click(function(){
     event.preventDefault();
     //Do your AJAX Stuff
  });
});
```

Also make sure that `action` attribute is empty in your form. It should work.

Even if the problem persists make sure that **ID attribute** is not used anywhere else.

Check out **[Jquery Docs -  preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)**

Comment: I think it will be more elegant if you place `event.preventDefault()` after `//Do AJAX Stuff`

Comment: No, it should be the first line cos it will help in preventing the redirection

Comment: It will prevent default handler anyway.

Comment: but its best practice to include it in the first line

Answer (score 0):

Put your button back in the form, and in the function which handles the click insert the following(at the start):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Where event is the argument of the function like this:

```
$( "#normalbutton" ).click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
.....
});
```

More info at: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 0):

Please check code 
Put type="button" in

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="button" id="normalbutton">Imabutton</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove the `<form>` tags. Either you can use the `button` type for the `<button>` tag or just use `<a> - hyper-link`. You can call your jQuery even through the `<a> - hyper-link`.

**If you could share the whole code it would help community members to answer it more quickly.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use return false on submit or onclick function

Using Jquery

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#normalbutton").click(function(){
       return false;
    });
});
</script>
```